# Using "How" + "did" + "the" (noun)

Tags: verbs

Is it correct to say:
"How did the problem started?"
"How did the war started?" and so on?

I think the difference there is if you are using "the". Can someone enlighten me if the base form of the verb should still be used?

Comment: Excuse me, but it should be *"start"* instead of *"started"* in both examples!

Comment: You are half right. It has nothing to do with the article "the", but the presence of the auxiliary verb "did" which requires a plain (infinitival) verb form as complement: _How did the problem start_?

Answer (score 1):

As SovereignSun's comment, the verb should be the "base" present tense.  The verb "to get" is often used with "how" to ask a question about a situation or condition.  In your two examples you could say either:

> How did the problem start?
>
> How did the problem get started?

The general form is "How did the (noun)(do or be something)?"

> How did the cat jump up on the roof?
>
> How did the palm tree grow so tall?
>
> How did the world get so complicated?

And so on.  Remember the definite article "the" is used when talking about something either *singular* or *already known* to your listener.  In my first sentence, for example, it is assumed that the listener knows which cat I mean.

Also, you do not use "the" before proper nouns (like names).

> How did Donald Trump manage to be President?

You may use the indefinite article if you are talking about something *in general* or the listener doesn't already know which of that thing you mean:

> How did a watermelon get in the bathtub?
>
> How did an airplane land in our backyard?
>
> How did a horse wander into the school?

Additionally, since you specify *did* and not *does*, this limits the scope of the question to things which happened at least partly in the past.  You can use *does* to ask about present or ongoing things:

> How does an airplane fly?
>
> How does the elephant eat with its trunk?
>
> How does Donald Trump keep his hair looking perfect?

Comment: "How did Donald Trump manage to be President?" makes me wonder. Does it mean he managed to be a president in the past? Shouldn't it instead be "become"?

Comment: @SovereignSun Good question.  "Become" is perfectly ok in this context, but I used "manage" to give the question the *nuance*, "**I** think it shouldn't have been possible, yet ..."

Comment: @SovereignSun Also it's meant to be a [rhetorical question](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/rhetorical), meaning a question where I'm making a statement, and don't expect an answer.

Comment: Still "be" and "become" have very different meaning!

Comment: @SovereignSun  True he's not president yet, so *technically* he can't, at the moment, *be* President.  But it's not unusual to project to an expected future condition when it's (more or less) certain.